# error getting time from phone in xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I trying to fetch the time from the phone's clock but am not able to fetch using this code

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger second = [components second];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components =
    [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger second = [components second];
```

You missed a line in the code.